# capacitor camera.pickimgaes selects multiple image in web but allows to select only image in android device gallery

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using ionic angular for building an application and I need to upload images from device gallery, and using capacitor **camera.pickImages()** plugin for selecting images from gallery but when run in web it allows to select multiple images but when trying on the actual android it allows to me select single image,

```
const images = await Camera.pickImages({

});
```

also it allows to select multiple images from google photos application in android device but doesnot allow to select multiple image from the device default gallery.

I am trying to build an mobile app so I am not trying to use
 method.

I am expecting to select multiple image or single when user tries to upload image from the device gallery

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At least provide your whole function together with the complete HTML tag where you call that function.